# Why is my github pages not displaying for all users?

Tags: github-pages

I made a portfolio website using a Jekyll template in Github Pages. 16 hours or so ago, I connected the Github pages site to a personal domain I purchased. I did so by creating a CNAME folder in the Pages repository and adding this CNAME as well as a few A variables to the DNS records with my domain provider (Domain.com) An hour or so after making these DNS changes, Github pages said my site was published on the new domain.

I shared the link to my new website with a few people. Several of them were able to access it without any issue; however, some reported that they received an empty white page when arriving to the site or a generic page with messaging along the lines of 'this domain hasn't been set up.' The failure to see the site seems to have no pattern across browser or device.

For me personally, I was able to see the site last night but this morning after deploying some new changes, I couldn't see the site for 30 minutes or so, until it suddenly worked again. During the time I couldn't see it, other friends reported that they were able to view it.

Any idea why this might be happening? I'm brand new to this stuff and I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`dnsmap.io`](https://dnsmap.io/) and check if the CNAME propagation is complete or still in progress.

You can see more at "[Why are my CNAME Records not propagating?](https://engage.activedemand.com/hc/en-us/articles/360046524294-Why-are-my-CNAME-Records-not-propagating-)": that would explain the empty white page.

That being said, this could also be affected by an [GitHub incident currently pending](https://www.githubstatus.com/incidents/d60fmldlvw48).